# Generic methods/Default methods in Ruby, when some method is not defined

Tags: ruby, oop, metaprogramming

I want to do something but I'm not sure if it is possible. I want to use "generic methods" or "default methods" in case when some method is called but is not defined. This is a simple example so you can understand my point:

This is the class:

```
class XYZ

    def a
        #...
    end

    def b
        #...
    end
end
```

The instance of the class XYZ:

```
n = XYZ.new
n.a
n.b
n.c
```

As you can see, I'm calling the method "c" which is not defined and it will throw an error. Can I do something in the class XYZ so when someone calls a method not defined get the name of the method and do something, in base of the name of the method? And, is this possible in another languages (not making a compiler)? If this is possible, how is it called (theory speaking)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`method_missing`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing):

```
class XYZ
  def a; end
  def b; end

  def method_missing(name, *args)
    "Called #{name} with args: #{args}"
  end
end

XYZ.new.c #=> "Called c"
```

You should also define [`respond_to_missing?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-respond_to_missing-3F) to get [`respond_to?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F) to work nicer in 1.9.2+. You should [read more about `respond_to?`/`respond_to_missing?` when using `method_missing`](http://blog.marc-andre.ca/2010/11/methodmissing-politely.html).

This, by the way, would be considered to be *metaprogramming*. This isn't typically possible in compiled languages because of the way they call functions.

Answer (score 3):

its called method_missing.
When you call a method that is not defined on object, ruby redirects the call to method_missing method which raises the error for you.

you can do this:

```
class XYZ
  def method_missing(method, *args, &blck)
    puts "called #{method} with arguments #{args.join(',')}"
  end
end
```

now instead of error you will get output to your console.